# Scrum master certification from other authorities than Scrum Alliance?

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

Having worked in Scrum for the past 5 years, a client of mine demands a formal certification. I certainly do not want to spend money for 2 day training of something I know quite well but I thought there is no other way. However, I found out that organization like GAQM offer SCM (though their trademark differs and reads "certified scrum master", with the space between the last two words) offers just the exam.

How valid and acknowledged would that be, does anyone have experience with certification outside the ScrumAlliance?

Comment: Even what about this www.scrumstudy.com certification? Is it valid one???

Comment: Out of curiosity (assuming you can get the answer without offending them :) ) - what is the client's reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a Professional Scrum Trainer with Scrum.org.

There are two well-recognized certification bodies for Scrum in the industry, Scrum Alliance and Scrum.org. These have been around for a long time, their certificates are backed by a strong community, brand and they both descend directly from Ken Schwaber and/or Jeff Sutherland, who are the authors of the Framework and the Scrum Guide.

### Scrum.org

Scrum.org offers you the ability to take its Scrum Master assessments without having to participate in a training. They have two:

- [Professional Scrum Master 1](https://www.scrum.org/Assessments/Professional-Scrum-Master-Assessments/PSM-I-Assessment)
- [Professional Scrum Master 2](https://www.scrum.org/Assessments/Professional-Scrum-Master-Assessments/PSM-II-Assessment)

### Scrum Alliance

The CSM assessment from Scrum Alliance can, as far as I can tell, only be taken after attending a course.

### Others

In the last year or so a number of additional "certification organisations" have sprung up. ScrumStudy is one of them, but their "Scrum Body Of Knowledge" book has been heavily debated in the broader community, as it approaches scrum far more as a Project Management Framework with all kinds of processes and practices, than an empirical Framework.

With Agile being hot and a lot of money to be made in online-training and certification, a number of parties have stepped into this market.

I've personally read through the materials, even attended some of the courses online and my personal conclusion is that if it's real Empirical scrum you want, then these organisations don't really hit the mark. To me these "other" certificates are not of sufficient value that I'd associate myself with them.

My personal opinion is that if I've never heard of a certification body, or if their material, commercial practices (like very similar naming conventions) or anything else looks suspicions, I'd have trouble "trusting" any certificate I'd receive from them :).

Comment: Thanks, so certification from Scrum.org seems much more legit. BTW, the other link does not work.